# How to rename JPG files with running order using Python

Tags: python-2.7, file, rename

I quite new in Python programming and i try to rename 100 files with ".jpg" extention, located in specific folder using pyhthon.

I need that the files will be renamed by running order start from number 1. This is the code i start writing:

```
import os,glob,fnmatch

os.chdir(r"G:\desktop\Project\test")
for files in glob.glob("*.jpg"):
    print files
```

When i run it, i get:

```
>>> 
er3.jpg
IMG-20160209-ssdeWA0000.jpg
IMG-20160209-WA0000.jpg
sd4.jpg
tyu2.jpg
uj7.jpg
we3.jpg
yh7.jpg
>>>
```

so the code, till now is OK.

For example my folder is:

[image]

and i need that all the files name will be:
1,2,3,4 - with running order names. Is it possible with python 2.7?

Comment: `for filename in sorted(glob.glob("*jpg")):` perhaps?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you simply want to rename all files as `1.jpg`, `2.jpg` etc. you can do this:

```
import os
import glob

os.chdir(r"G:\desktop\Project\test")
for index, oldfile in enumerate(glob.glob("*.jpg"), start=1):
    newfile = '{}.jpg'.format(index)
    os.rename (oldfile,newfile)
```

[`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) is used to get get the index of each file from the list returned by `glob()`, so that it can be used to create the new filename. Note that it allows you to specify the start index, so I've started from `1`, rather than Python Standard, zero

If you want this list of files to be sortable properly, you'll want the filename to be padded with zero's as well (`001.jpg`, etc.). In which case simply replace `newfile = '{}.jpg'.format(index)'` with `newfile = '{:03}.jpg'.format(index)`.

See the [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings) for more on `str.format()`

Comment: Would it be possible to adapt this to handle jpg and png?

Comment: @Maverick: Of course. Unfortunately, `glob.glob()` can only match one extension at a time, but you could easily run the loop twice, substituting `jpg` for `png`. There are other, more efficient ways of doing it also, it very much depends on what your desired output is.

Answer (score 1):

To rename all the JPG files from a particular folder First, get the list of all the files contain in the folder.

> [os.listdir](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html?highlight=os.listdir#os.listdir) will give you list all the files in images path.
>
> use [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) to get the index numbers to get the new name for
>   images.

```
import os
images_path = r"D:\shots_images"
image_list = os.listdir(images_path)
for i,  image in enumerate(image_list):
    ext = os.path.splitext(image)[1]
    if ext == '.jpg':
        src = images_path + '/' + image
        dst = images_path + '/' + str(i) + '.jpg'
        os.rename(src, dst)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
from os import path
os.chdir("//Users//User1//Desktop//newd//pics")

for file in os.listdir():
    name,ext=path.splitext(file)
    if ext == '.jpeg':
        dst= '{}.jpg'.format(name)
        os.rename(file,dst)
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)